# Euclidean transformation of three points using reflections

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, transformation, reflection

A Euclidean transformation $E$ sends the point $A = (0, 0)$ to the point $E(A) = (1, 1)$,
the point $B = (1, 0)$ to the point $E(B) = (1, 2)$, and the point $C = (0, 1)$ to the
point $E(C) = (2, 1)$.

Find equations of lines $l_1, l_2$ and $l_3$ such that the transformation $E$ can be
represented by a reflection in the line $l_1$, followed by a reflection in the line $l_2$,
followed by a reflection in the line $l_3$.

I'm told it is a glide reflection and the solution I've been provided is:

$l_1= y=-1$

$l_2=x=1$

$l_3=y=1$

But I have tried obtaining the image from these and it's not possible. I was wondering if there was a mistake in the solution or if I am not seeing something myself. I got

$l_1= y=x-1$

$l_2=y=-2$

$l_3=y=-1$

This seems to work but when reading it says a glide reflection is achieved by a reflection in a line followed by reflections in two lines, both of which are perpendicular to the original, but these are not so I am not sure if it's right?

Comment: The transformation is uniquely determined by its effect on the three given points. If what you’ve come up with has the right effect on them, then it’s correct.

Answer (score 0):

The given solution is wrong. Let's look at point $A$. Reflection through $l_1$ yields $(0,-2)$. Then when reflected through $l_2$ you get $(2,-2)$. The last step $l_3$ yields $E(A)=(2,5)\ne(1,1)$

Comment: Is the transformation still a glide reflection? Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Your original translation of the glide is $(1,1)$. To check if it is a glide reflection, test that applying the operation twice yields a translation, twice the one of the glide. That is $E(E(A))-A=E(E(B))-B=E(E(C))-C=(2,2)$